# SI5351 Breakout 153,600Hz Square Wave Signal

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, adafruit, oscillator-clock

I'm trying to generate a consistent 153,600Hz square wave signal with 50% duty cycle from a Adafruit SI5351 3.3-5v breakout board for use as a fixed synchronous serial clock reference, but the closest frequency I get from it is 142,857Hz which is too far off the target.

Originally, I followed [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-si5351-clock-generator-breakout/wiring-and-test) article (my device looks exactly like the one in the pictures) from Adafruit to no avail. I tried using the Adafruit library and the mentioned ClockBuilder software, but the article makes no mention of how to apply the values returned from the software into code, and messing with the values myself didn't help either.

So, I then moved on to using [this](https://github.com/etherkit/Si5351Arduino) library from etherkit. It's has a lot simpler interface, and was easy for me to get at least something being output.

Here is my current code using the etherkit library running on my Arduino Mega. It seems to only output 142,857Hz, even though I specified my target frequency of 153,600Hz.

```cpp
//Arduino Mega
#include "si5351.h"
#include "Wire.h"

Si5351 si5351;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    if (!si5351.init(SI5351_CRYSTAL_LOAD_8PF, 0, 0))
    {
      Serial.print("Cannot communicate with SI5351.");
    }
    else
    {
      si5351.drive_strength(SI5351_CLK0, SI5351_DRIVE_8MA);
      si5351.output_enable(SI5351_CLK0, 1);
      si5351.set_freq(153600ULL * 100ULL, SI5351_CLK0);
    }
}

void loop(){}
```

But here is where it gets odd: I can set the frequency argument of `set_freq` to anything under `120000ULL * 100ULL` and the output will be spot on, but anything above that amount will "snap" back to 142,857Hz, up to `190000ULL * 100ULL`.

The other thing I got working against me is that I don't have access to a oscilloscope to more accurately measure it's output. My current solution is a Arduino UNO acting as a frequency measuring tool, running the following code:

```cpp
//Arduino Uno
#define pin_MeasureThis A0

volatile unsigned long on_time;
volatile unsigned long off_time;

float lfreq;
float freq;
char freq_str[12];
char msg[32];

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pin_MeasureThis, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  on_time = pulseIn(pin_MeasureThis, HIGH);
  off_time = pulseIn(pin_MeasureThis, LOW);
  freq = 1000000 / (on_time + off_time);

  if (freq >= 0 && freq < 999999)
  {
      dtostrf(freq, 8, 0, freq_str);
  }

  if (freq != lfreq)
  {
    lfreq = freq;

    sprintf(msg, "%sHz", freq_str);
    Serial.println(msg);
  }
}
```

I tested my measuring code by comparing it's measurement against visible frequencies with a LED and it performed perfectly. I do understand that probably doesn't scale well for higher frequencies, but I really have no better way right now.

Here is a sample of the exact serial output I get back from my Arduino UNO measuring the CLK0 output of the SI5351 breakout board:

```
  ...
  142857Hz
  125000Hz
  142857Hz
  125000Hz
  ...
```

Any advice on how to get to a steady 153,600Hz signal would be much appreciated. Thanks.